# What is the way to create a BitmapDecoder and a SoftwareBitmap with vb.Net

Tags: .net, vb.net, bitmap, ocr

I try to get the text of a picture shape in Microsoft Word. For this I use the OCR library which is included in windows 10 `windows.media.ocr`. Because the `OCREngine` needs a `SoftwareBitmap` which I haven't worked with yet I tried the following approach to get to this `SoftwareBitmap`:

```
  oWordDocument.Shapes(1).Select() '*** Get shape and copy to clipboard and then to bitmap
  oWordApp.Selection.CopyAsPicture()
  Dim oBitmap As System.Drawing.Bitmap = New System.Drawing.Bitmap(System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.GetImage())

  Dim oSoftwareBitmap As Windows.Graphics.Imaging.SoftwareBitmap
  Dim oUWPStream As Windows.Storage.Streams.IRandomAccessStream

  Using oNetStream As New System.IO.MemoryStream '*** Get UWP-Stream via .Net-Stream
        oBitmap.Save(oNetStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
        oUWPStream = System.IO.WindowsRuntimeStreamExtensions.AsRandomAccessStream(oNetStream)

        '*** in the following line an invalidcast error occurs "Unable to cast object of type 'System.__ComObject' to type 'Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapDecoder'."
        Dim oBitmapDecoder As Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapDecoder = Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapDecoder.PngDecoderId, oUWPStream)
        oSoftwareBitmap = oBitmapDecoder.GetSoftwareBitmapAsync()
  End Using
```

**So right now the code runs fine until I try to create the BitmapDecoder.** From what I can see I provide a valid RandomAccessStream but the create fails with invalid.

Can someone please help on this or even provide or point me to a code sample for creating the BitmapDecoder and SoftwareBitmap?

Sorry if the description is complicated or confusing - english is not my native language

Problem solved: Actually the solution was quite simple. I just didn't understand it the first time. I was aware from the beginning that I should have used await with the async methods, but I always ran into not very helpful error messages from the visual editor. And this was simply due to the missing async context. After I added the async keyword to my Event-Handler `Private Async Sub SelectFilesButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SelectFilesButton.Click` everything went fine and I could use the await statement as expected.

Here is the final solution corresponding to the code above:

```
'*** Get Bitmap from Word Bitmap-Shape
oWordDocument.Shapes(1).Select()
oWordApp.Selection.CopyAsPicture()
Dim oBitmap As System.Drawing.Bitmap = New System.Drawing.Bitmap(System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.GetImage())

'*** Convert Streams, get BitmapDecoder + SoftwareBitmap
Using oNetStream As New System.IO.MemoryStream
    oBitmap.Save(oNetStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
    Dim oUWPStream As Windows.Storage.Streams.IRandomAccessStream = System.IO.WindowsRuntimeStreamExtensions.AsRandomAccessStream(oNetStream)
    Dim oBitmapDecoder As Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapDecoder = Await Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(oUWPStream)
    Dim oSoftwareBitmap As Windows.Graphics.Imaging.SoftwareBitmap = Await oBitmapDecoder.GetSoftwareBitmapAsync()
End Using
```

Thanks Jimi for pointing me into the right direction - sorry for taking me so long to understand

PS: Very helpful to understand this were 2 articles from microsoft programming guides which you can find using the following search terms:
"**Control Flow in Async Programs (Visual Basic)**" and
"**Asynchronous Programming with Async and Await (Visual Basic)**"

Comment: FWIW there are three ways you can extract the graphic image from Word: Clipboard (what you have), the method to Save as a picture, extracting the image from the WordOpenXML. Via the Clipboard is probably not bad because you can request the information in the graphics format you need. Note that if the Shape has had text added to it by editing it from *within Word* you can extract that text directly using the object model.

Comment: Hi Cindy, thanks for the help. I made some changes to the question. My current problem seems to be the BitmapDecoder or SoftwareBitmap creation. The problem is not exclusively related to Word. Word is just one possible environment which can hold bitmap data which can feed the Ocr-Engine. I'm familiar with the office object model having built VSTO applications but I have no knowledge about the UWP part.

Comment: `BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync()` returns an `IAsyncOperation<BitmapDecoder>`. You should `await CreateAsync()`, in an async context (an async method).

Comment: Hi Jimi, thanks for the help. I was also thinking about that being the problem. I just couldn't find a source where I could find how to do this in VB.Net. Do you know of any or could provide some additional information?

Comment: To do what in VB? An async method?

Comment: Yes - When I use async I needs a lot of stuff around this which I don't understand right now. In C# it looks so easy...

Comment: VB.Net and C# async methods are exactly the same. Only the position of the type declaration changes. C# => `private async Task<int> MyMethodAsync() { return await SomeMethodWhichReturnsIntAsync(); }`  VB: `Private Async Function MyMethodAsync() As Task(Of Integer)  Return Await SomeMethodWhichReturnsIntAsync()   End Function`. You can call an async method from another async method if you need to wait for the results or use a proxy async method from a non-async method to call your worker async method (when you want a fire-and-forget async proc, because you don't need to wait for its results).

Comment: Sorry Jimi - I can't figure out how to use this information for my case. I'm still not able to write code which creates a BitmapDecoder object and afterwards a  SoftwareBitmap object